# Truffle contract factory test with Javascript

Tags: solidity, truffle, mocha, binance-smart-chain, test

Here is my smart contract source code.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.9;

contract CampaignFactory {
  address[] public deployedCampaigns;

  function createCampaign(uint minimum) public {
     Campaign newCompaign  = new Campaign(minimum, msg.sender);
     deployedCampaigns.push(address(newCompaign));
  }

  function getDeployedCampaigns() public view returns(address[] memory){
     return deployedCampaigns;
  }

}

contract Campaign {

  struct Request {
    string description;
    uint amount;
    address recipient;
    bool complete;
    uint approvalCount;
    mapping (address => bool) approvals;
  }
  mapping(address => bool) approvers;
  uint approversCount;
  Request[] requests;

  address public manager;
  uint public minimumContribution;

  modifier restricted() {
    require(msg.sender == manager);
    _;
  }
  constructor(uint minimum, address creator) {
    manager = creator;
    minimumContribution = minimum;
  }

  function contribute() public payable {
    require(msg.value > minimumContribution);
    approvers[msg.sender] = true;
    approversCount++;
  }

  function createRequest(string memory description, uint amount, address recipient) public 
   restricted{

     Request storage newRequest = requests.push();
     newRequest.description = description;
     newRequest.amount = amount;
     newRequest.recipient = recipient;
     newRequest.complete = false;
     newRequest.approvalCount = 0;    
  }
  ...
}
```

Truffle javascript test code :

```
const {assert} = require('chai');
const Web3 = require('web3');
const ganache = require('ganache-cli');
const web3 = new Web3(ganache.provider());

const CampaignFactory = artifacts.require('./CampaignFactory');
const Campaign = artifacts.require('./Campaign');

contract('CampaignFactory', (accounts) => {
  let factory;
  let campaign;
  let campaignAddress;

  before( async () => {
    factory = await CampaignFactory.deployed();   

    // We create a campaign instance but not get a reference to the campaign instance.
    // Remember that anytime we send a transaction we get absolutely no result back except for 
    // a transaction receipt
    const childContractTx = await factory.createCampaign(web3.utils.toWei('0.02', 'ether'));
    campaignAddress = childContractTx.receipt.to;        
    campaign = await Campaign.at(campaignAddress);     
  })
  describe('CampaignFactory deployment', async () =>{
    it('successfully deployed', async () => {
      const address = await factory.address 
      assert.notEqual(address, '')
      assert.notEqual(address, null)
      assert.notEqual(address, undefined)
      assert.notEqual(address, 0x0)
    })

    it('successfully created a campaign', async ()=> {
      const address = await campaign.address;     
      assert.notEqual(address, '')
      assert.notEqual(address, null)
      assert.notEqual(address, undefined)
      assert.notEqual(address, 0x0)      
    })

  })
  describe('Campaign', async ()=> {    
    it('contribute', async ()=> {                   
      const manager = await campaign.manager();
      console.log("manager", manager)
      assert.equal(accounts[0], manager);
    })
  })
}
```

The below is the result of test :
[image]

The "Campaign" instance was created and deployed by CampaignFactory.
"manager" is a public state variable of "Campaign" smart contract. So I tried to read it through its default getter. But it was failed. What's wrong with me?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this line:

```
campaignAddress = childContractTx.receipt.to;
```

the transaction of the following line is executing the function **createCampaign** of the factory smart contract

```
 const childContractTx = await factory.createCampaign(web3.utils.toWei('0.02', 'ether'));
```

so the value of **childContractTx.receipt.to** is the address of factory contract and not the campaign contract address

you should use something like this:

```
campaignAddress = await factory.deployedCampaigns(0);
campaign = await Campaign.at(campaignAddress);
```

since the function createCampaign is storing the address in the array:
deployedCampaigns

in this line of your smart contract:

```
deployedCampaigns.push(address(newCompaign));
```